# Yii2: Registering Asset Bundle vs registering external Js file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii2

Hi I wanted to know the advantage of registering Asset Bundle following the process described in the docs like
**Process one**
in AppAsset.php

```
public $js = [
        'js/myjsfile.js'
    ];
```

then in the view file
adding Namespace like

```
namespace app\assets;
```

and then adding the use statement like

```
use app\assets\AppAsset;
AppAsset::register($this);
```

Instead of doing all this if I use
**Process Two**

```
$this->registerJs('js/myjsfile.js', $this::POS_READY);
```

it works fine.
So why should I use **Process One**.

1. Any advantage and reason for this will be greatly appreciated.
2. If I follow the **process one** Do I need to add all the js files in
       AppAsset.php individually.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One of the main reasons for using an Asset Bundle is that your assets' paths will always be correct. Consider:

```
$this->registerJsFile('js/myjsfile.js', ['position'=>$this::POS_READY]);
```

will generate something like:

```
<script src="js/myjsfile.js"></script>
```

Which works great for non urlManager enabled urls, e.g. `http://localhost/yiiproject/index.php?r=user/update&id=8` because your browser looks for the js file at: `/yiiproject/js/myjsfile.js`

But if you enable urlManager, your url will look like `http://localhost/yiiproject/user/update/8`, which means your browser will look for your js file at: `/yiiproject/user/update/8/js/myjsfile.js`.

You could overcome this problem by using:

```
$this->registerJsFile(Yii::$app->request->baseUrl.'/js/myjsfile.js', ['position'=>$this::POS_READY]);
```

But the Asset Bundle basicly does that for you.

Comment: Hi Deacs - That answers why use AssetBundle. can you also tell me that whether I need to include all the js files individually in AppAsset.php.

Comment: I have the same question. If I have multiple views, and each view has its own css/js, does it mean I need to create asset bundle for each of them?

Comment: @Jerry yeah I would create an AssetBundle for each bundle of seperate css and js files. In most cases though, more than 1 view will use the same assets so you can reuse the AssetBundle.

Comment: your code example is incorrect. registerJs is used for js code block. (http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-view.html#registerJs()-detail). registerJsFile should be used

Answer (score 10):

Asset Bundles have some advantages over normal registering. Apart from what @deacs said in his/her  answer here are others:

1. Assets Bundles can publish the file to assets if its not in web accessible directory
2. Assets Bundle can deal with less files (in case of CSS) as well as compressing the assets.
3. Makes Code Elegant especially in solving dependencies and hence reusability

All the features that makes bundles shine are found in [docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-assets.html)

Answer (score 0):

Using Asset Bundles, you can also get the latest version from 'vendor' folder, so if you need to update some lib you don't need to manually do this since composer already do this.