# What's wrong with using <script> tags in main Layout instead of using AssetBundle in Yii PHP framework?

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I have write permission issues on my hosting account. Would it be ok to add script and link tags in the Layout file instead of using AssetBundle or registerJs?
 What are the advantages and disadvantages?

**EDIT:**
I'm using Google App Engine, without cloud storage access. Registering an Asset Bundle creates new directories which is not allowed on App Engine. I know the advantages of Asset Bundle, but my focus is on finding out if there's anything WRONG with the `<script>` tags, the accepted answer is perfect answer to my question.

Comment: Refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28140166/yii2-registering-asset-bundle-vs-registering-external-js-file

Comment: yes, there are some answers that address my issue. Do you care to write an answer? your own version? :)

Comment: You can minify on the fly loaded scripts or put them into one file to speed up page loading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation don't affirm that the direct assign of script or link tag is wrong .. the doc affirm is preferred and that is often preferable .. This because the assetManagement make these assigmenent indirectly and the indipendent by specific position and location .. The single asset 
allows you to keep all the necessary dependencies neatly organized on the same side configuration ..

Another possibility is the use of registering script [(see..)](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-client-scripts.html)

Answer (score 3):

Separating frontend logic (js scripts) from layout have several benefits from my point of view.

- Reusability. You dont need to copy-paste your scripts, just add them as dependency in AssetBundles.
- Ease of modification and expansion. If asset dependency changed somehow, you dont need to make changes across all views, just do it in one place.
- Automation. You can't use tools like Gulp, Grunt, Webpack with inline scripts.
- Maintenance. Managing dependencies in one place and having all frontend code in one centralized location is much more convenient.
- Caching. Scripts injected directly in html code are never cached.

Comment: How does it feel with a plus25 :) ? You are good at Yii, we can help each other, pareekbhagu(at)gmail. Well written answer. AssetBundles create problem when deployed at Google App Engine. Any idea how to disable them ?

Comment: As far as I know, Google App Engine has read-only file system. So if you want to use AssetBundles you should implement your own AssetManager to utilize Google Cloud Storage, which is not trivial task.