# Is it possible to link JavaScript files using <script src=""> in view files in yii 2

Tags: javascript, php, html, yii2-advanced-app

Firstly, I developed yii 1 applcation. In the application, I linked js files like this:

```
<script src="<?php echo Yii::app()->theme->baseUrl;?>/Index/script_nav.js"></script>
```

Is it possible to link JavaScript files using  in yii 2 or should I link js files using appasset?

Comment: there must be a framework way to embed `js` & `css`

Comment: yes you can add

Comment: see this http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-client-scripts.html#registering-scripts

Answer (score 1):

yii2 provides [registerJsFile()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-view.html#registerJsFile()-detail) function to inlucde js files.

```
<?php $this->registerJsFile('js/company-index.js'); ?>
```

And **Yes** you can include the js files with `script` tag.

```
<script src="<?php echo Yii::$app->request->baseUrl;?>/js/youFile.js"></script>
```

but you should use `registerJsFile`, See this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/28142370/3143384

Answer (score 0):

You can use that in **layout file**

Path

> views->layout->main.php

Like simple as

```
 <script src="myscripts.js"></script>
```

For checking its linked or not use inspect element -> network (open this before landing page)

Here you can see your files.