# Registering asset files in yii2 view fails

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have tried this

```
<?php
  $this->registerJS(Yii::getAlias("@web/themes/webwise/assets/js/core/libraries
 /bootstrap.min.js"), \yii\web\VIEW::POS_HEAD);
 ?>
```

This fails to correctly insert the styles

The folllowing is generated on the html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 /test/advanced/themes/webwise/assets/js/core/libraries/bootstrap.min.js</script>
```

The above fails since there is no href in the generated output

I have tried with

```
 <?php
  $this->registerJsFile(Yii::getAlias("@web/themes/webwise/assets/js/core/libraries
 /bootstrap.min.js"), \yii\web\VIEW::POS_HEAD);
 ?>
```

As pointend in the yii2 documentation but returns an error

```
Cannot use a scalar value as an array
```

Where am i going wrong, The file bootstrap.min.js is only used in certain controller action so i cannot extend yii2 bootstrap asset

I have checked on [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28140166/yii2-registering-asset-bundle-vs-registering-external-js-file) but its not very helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think in this way is correct

```
<?php
  $this->registerJsFile(Yii::getAlias("@web/themes/webwise/assets/js/core/libraries
 /bootstrap.min.js"), ['position'=>  \yii\web\View::POS_HEAD]);
 ?>
```

The second parameter is an array.

Answer (score 0):

If you use advanced template the problem may be that you need to use `@webroot` instead of `@web`

```
    <?php $this->registerJsFile(Yii::getAlias("@webroot/themes/webwise/assets/js/core/libraries
 /bootstrap.min.js"), ['position' => \yii\web\VIEW::POS_HEAD]); ?>
```

---

but it's more appropriate to use assets you can read more about it in [docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-assets.html), [API docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-assetbundle.html)

Comment: @webroot fails by returning an error of cant access the file path, the server has limitations on the paths accessed,  webroot returns the full path from c directory thats why its fails